# Need help understanding this exercise's solution

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, signature, keys

We were given this exercise, which asks us to identify the types of keys used on this diagram:

[image]

**The solution was**

Kxa -> A's private key

Kya -> A's public key

KxB -> B's private key

My question is, how is it possible that B knows the contents the first message coming from A since it was encrypted with A's private key ? 
Also, B replies back to A encrypting the message with A's public key which is encrypting a message using B's private key.. I thought private keys were meant to be used to decrypt messages ecrypted by public keys.

I dont understand how come they know each other's private keys.

Comment: The private key operation is probably used for signing, not encryption - and therefore the public key for verification (possibly with message recovery?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so this takes a bit of guessing, but I'm assuming the following:

- `A` is the identity of A, which can be used to *select* the right public key of A;
- `Kxa()` is a signing operation (with message recovery) that signs the random `Ra` and a tag `Ts` which is used as proof;
- `Kya()` is an encryption operation with the public key A, so that the session key `Ks` is kept confidential;
- `Kxb()` is a signing operation (with message recovery) that signs the random `Ra` together with session key `Ks`;
- `Ks(M)` is message encryption with the established session key `Ks`.

The general idea seems to be to perform authentication of both parties and session key establishment for message transport security.

Comment: Note that this is a strange protocol, signature generation with message recovery is not a regular operation (anymore).